# How do I get JetBrains IDE's auto-save to work correctly when used inside a virtual machine?

Tags: editor, pycharm, virtual-machine, virtualbox, jetbrains-ide

The default auto-save behavior is "Save files on frame deactivation". However, I'm using it inside a virtual machine, so the frame deactivation is not detected, because the frame I'm deactivating is actually VirtualBox's window in the host machine.

The only other supported way seems to be saving it periodically every second or two, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. It would be ideal if it can save whenever I press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, but I'm not sure if it is possible to trigger a save on just the `Alt` key alone. Or maybe there's a way to externally trigger a save command through some API.

I'm wondering if anyone encountered similar problems when using JetBrains IDEs (in my case PyCharm) inside a virtual machine. Any advice?

Comment: You cannot assign just modifier key (`Alt`, `Ctrl` or `Shift`) to any action -- it has to be combination with "significant/real" key as well (letter/number/F-key etc). Is there any reason why can't you use standard (well, it depends on Keymap actually) `Ctrl+S` to save files when needed? Why it needs to be on "every few seconds" basis? AFAIK there is some RPC that IDE supports .. but I'm not sure that "Save files" would be there.

Comment: I develop on PyCharm and Jupyter. Most of the time, I use the IDE only for editing, and execute code from the browser. So if I forget to hit ctrl-s, it runs outdated code and can be confusing to debug at times. I'm trying to use auto-save.